# Ruby on Rails cannot Send Get Request with CoffeeScript and AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, coffeescript

Soo, I have this validation I am trying to setup using an AJAX and Coffee Script get request. This request calls a method on the RoR controller and is suppose to send back data. However, it is not working. This is my first go at Coffee Script so please be gentle, I'm just a baby.

My error -> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/home/get_email/test@test.com"):

Do I need to create a route for my AJAX GET request? Code below.

Assume the .change function does it's job and enters my AJAX cal
l as expected.

###Coffee Script AJAX###

```
jQuery ->
  $('#txt_email').blur ->
    @data
    @txtemail = $('#txt_email').val()

    $.ajax 'home/get_email/' + @txtemail,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "JSON",
      asnyc: false,
      success: (data) ->
        console.log(data)
```

###Home Controller Method###

```
def get_email(email)
     @db_email = User.where(["email = ?", email]).first
     respond_to do |format|
       if @db_email != nil
         format.js {}
         format.json { render json: @db_email }
       else
         format.html { render action: 'index' }
         format.json { render json @db_email.email, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
    end
 end
```

Making some progress. Currently here is what is occurring. Seems like the id param is not being populated, but the "email" text value is coming through. I also updated the Coffee JS to pass the txt_email value properly.

```
Parameters: {"email"=>"test@test.com", "id"=>"get_email"}
  Animal Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "animals".* FROM "animals" WHERE "animals"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "get_email"]]
```

###Routes###

```
    home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)       home#index
    home_show GET    /home/show(.:format)        home#show
     profile_new GET    /profile/new(.:format)      profile#new
     root GET    /                           home#index
          GET    /home(.:format)             home#index
          POST   /home(.:format)             home#create
     new_home GET    /home/new(.:format)         home#new
     edit_home GET    /home/:id/edit(.:format)    home#edit
     home GET    /home/:id(.:format)         home#show
          PATCH  /home/:id(.:format)         home#update
          PUT    /home/:id(.:format)         home#update
          DELETE /home/:id(.:format)         home#destroy
     profile_index GET    /profile(.:format)          profile#index
          POST   /profile(.:format)          profile#create
    new_profile GET    /profile/new(.:format)      profile#new
    edit_profile GET    /profile/:id/edit(.:format) profile#edit
    profile GET    /profile/:id(.:format)      profile#show
          PATCH  /profile/:id(.:format)      profile#update
          PUT    /profile/:id(.:format)      profile#update
          DELETE /profile/:id(.:format)      profile#destroy
```

#### Here is the Full Solution

Final code

```
$(txtemail).blur ->

if theEmailIsRegistered($(this).val()) is false
        $('#lbl_error_email').html('The entered e-mail is already in use.')
      else
        $('#lbl_error_email').html('')

theEmailIsRegistered = (email) ->

    $.ajax 'home/get_email/',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: {email: email }
      async: false,
      success: (data) ->

        if data is true
          return true
        else
          return false

  def get_email()
     @db_email = User.where(email: params[:email]).first
     respond_to do |format|
       if @db_email.present? && @db_email.email == params[:email]
         format.js {}
         format.json { render json: true }
       else
         format.js
         format.json { render json: false }
       end
     end
  end
```

Custom Route

```
get 'home/get_email' => 'home#get_email'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the problem is because of controller-action. it is not supposed to be in this format `def some_action(some_parameter) ; end`. To fix this , you have to do something like below

do this

```
 $.ajax 'home/get_email' , 
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "JSON",
  data: 
    email: @txtemail
  asnyc: false,
  success: (data) ->
    console.log(data)
```

And in `homes_controller` do this

```
def get_email
  @db_email = User.where(email: params[:email]).first
  respond_to do |format|
  if @db_email != nil
   format.js {}
   format.json { render json: @db_email }
  else
   format.html { render action: 'index' }
   format.json { render json @db_email.email, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. What purpose does email:email serve? @ParitoshPiplewar

Comment: oops, that was typo. It is actually a data object. like this `data: {email: 'example.com'}`

Comment: so this is my generated SQL - Animal Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "animals".* FROM "animals" WHERE "animals"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "get_email"]] . Is the id literally get_email? Or am I to assume that 'get_email' is actually the param i am passing in.

Comment: include the routes file.

Comment: maybe not, including routes… @ParitoshPiplewar

Comment: I am guessing I need to create a custom route for my get_email route?

Comment: yes. you have to put something  like this `get 'home/get_email' => 'home#get_email'` before `/home/show` route

Comment: I think I should be using a param in my controller   User Load (16.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (email = 'email') ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  The SQL is using 'emai' (:email) rather than the param. I changed the route, which worked.  @ParitoshPiplewar

Comment: check the `@txtemail` scope. it should work, try putting some value like `exampple@gmail.com` in place of `@textemail`. If that works, then there is a problem in `@` scoping.

Comment: yep, it is scoping. Thanks for all the help.